# nodejs response HTML file that contain script tag with src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to send a html file that contain js file path.
This html file is in below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="main">
        <input id="id" name="id" type="text" placeholder="ID"/> <br>
        <input id="passwd" name="passwd" type="password" placeholder="password"/> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="login" id="login">
    </form>
    <script src="./index_func.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I send this HTML file via express server index_func.js occurs 404 not found error
[image]

And This is a router to send html file

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/login.html'));
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Where is the `index_func.js` file located?

Comment: You have to create a static folder and add a file there

Comment: index_func.js is in views directory, same path with the HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add static routing in your express project.

Create a folder `public` in your project and put `index_func.js` inside it. Then add `express.static('public')` as a route middleware.

Something like this -

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.use(express.static('public'));

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/login.html'));
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Further reading - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html